# Magento 2: Trouble shooting setup:di:compile

Tags: upgrade, magento2.2.6, magento-2.2.1

I am in the process to upgrade in existing 2.2.1 installation to 2.2.6.

When I am running `setup:di:compile` it stops abruptly without throwing any error.

Do it log the error somewhere or 
what is other way to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try running with verbosity

```
magento -vvv setup:di:compile
```

php logs depend on your system configuration

```
php --info | grep error
```

http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log